# Getting an object from new Statement

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, combobox

I'm trying to get all Removable devices to put them into a Combobox.

```
_cbDevice.DataSource = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(d => d.IsReady == true && d.DriveType == DriveType.Removable).Select(n =>        
new { obj = n, disp = (n.Name + " " + n.VolumeLabel) }).ToList();
_cbDevice.DisplayMember = "disp";
_cbDevice.ValueMember = "obj";
```

Now I want to get the DriveInfo Object (which is "obj") when the SelectedIndex of the Combobox is changed. By simply casting the SelectedValue (or SelectedItem) I'll get an Invalid Cast Exception.

```
Additional Informations: The object of Type "
<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.IO.DriveInfo,System.String]" can not be converted into 
"System.IO.DriveInfo".
```

Hopefully s.o. can solve that problem

Comment: Is this `WebForms`, `WinForms`, `Wpf`?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I'm developing in WinForms but I don't think this matters or am I wrong?

Comment: Side note: please avoid discussion on how hard your life is. It generally obvious from the question already how much time you've spent searching for solution and, similar to ["thank you very much really appreciated"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), it does not add details/information to the post.

Comment: Okay, sorry I'm pretty new to StackOverflow, I just wanted not to start my text describing my problem.. I'll keep it in mind for my next questions, thank you

Comment: Your code works.  Post how you are casting it because `(DriveInfo)_cbDevice.SelectedValue` should work.

Comment: I'm casting it with (DriveInfo)_dvDevice.SelectedValue as you said. I'm confused because the DisplayMember works fine but the ValueMember contains according to the Exception not just the DriveInfo as defined but also a string (I think it's [obj, disp] but I don't know why)